On the definition of the stress tensor in two-dimensional CFTs
I started studying CFT recently. I'm following mostly the yellow book by Di Francesco et al. and the shorter book by Blumenhagen and Plauschinn. I'm currently studying how operator product expansions (OPEs) involving the stress tensor and a field can be used to characterize that field as a primary.
I'm a bit puzzled, however, on how the stress tensor is to be defined. For example, in general relativity I would define the stress tensor according to
$$T_{\mu\nu} = - \frac{2}{\sqrt{|g|}} \frac{\delta S}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}},$$
where $S$ is the action for the theory. In spite of this, Blumenhagen and Plauschinn, when studying a free boson system on p. 47, define
$$T_{\mu\nu} = 4 \pi \kappa \gamma \frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}} \frac{\delta S}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}, \tag{2.84 in B&P}$$
where $\kappa$ is a parameter that occurs in the action and $\gamma$ is a new parameter that they introduced to force a specific field to be a primary later on. This seems a bit sneaky for me. Why is it possible to multiply the stress tensor by a constant and use it to change which fields are primaries?
Something similar occurs in the calculations by Di Francesco et al. In Eq. (5.40), for example, they define a ``renormalized stress tensor'' by defining $T(z) = - 2 \pi T_{zz}(z)$, hence multiplying the actual stress tensor by a constant factor. I believe this is similar (and perhaps equivalent) to B&P's approach.
Why are these manipulations allowed? Shouldn't primary fields have a very specific OPE with the "true" stress tensor defined as in general relativity?

In theory, there is no "actual" stress tensor. You can rescale it as you like, as long as you keep your conventions consistent.
In practice (i.e., by widely accepted convention), the stress tensor normalization is fixed so that its self-OPE has the form
$$
T_{zz}(z) T_{ww}(w) \sim \frac{c/2}{(z-w)^4} + \frac{2T(w)}{(z-w)^2} + \frac{\partial T(w)}{z-w} \tag{1}
$$
Alternatively, you can also fix the normalization by requiring that the OPE of the stress tensor with another conformal primary has the form
$$
T_{zz}(z) O(w,{\bar w}) \sim \frac{h  O(w,{\bar w})}{(z-w)^2} + \frac{\partial  O(w,{\bar w})}{z-w} \tag{2}
$$
It can be shown that both ways of fixing the normalization are consistent.
